# String[] to indivdual strings

Tags: java, string

I don't really know how to word the question, because i dont really understand how to do it

I've got two '.java' files

createFile:

```
public void addRecords(String Package, String ClassName, String[] ListOfBoxes)
{
    format.format("%s", "package " + Package + ";"\n");
    format.format("%s", "@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)\n");
    format.format("%s", "public class " + ClassName + " extends ModelBiped\n");
    format.format("%s", "{\n");
    format.format("%s", "    ModelRenderer " + ListOfBoxes + ";\n");
    format.format("%s", "}\n");

   }
```

code i'm trying to run

```
            createFile file = new createFile();
    file.openFile();
    String[] Boxes = {"test1", "test2", "test3"};
    file.addRecords("default", "ModelTest", Boxes);         
    file.closeFile();
```

this is the output:

```
package net.minecraft.client.model;
@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public class ModelTest extends ModelBiped
{
    ModelRenderer [Ljava.lang.String;@3794d372;
}
```

this is what i want

```
package net.minecraft.client.model;
@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public class ModelTest extends ModelBiped
{
    ModelRenderer test1;
    ModelRenderer test2;
    ModelRenderer test3;
}
```

this is probably very simple but i'm a noob at java

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for createFile:

```
public void addRecords(String Package, String ClassName, String[] ListOfBoxes)
{
    format.format("%s", "package " + Package + ";"\n");
    format.format("%s", "@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)\n");
    format.format("%s", "public class " + ClassName + " extends ModelBiped\n");
    format.format("%s", "{\n");
    for (String box : listOfBoxes)
    {
        format.format("%s", "    ModelRenderer " + box + ";\n");
    }
    format.format("%s", "}\n");

}
```

The difference is that this code renders each element in the array, while your code renders the entire array in one go.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `Arrays.deepToString` method. Rewrite the corresponding line in your `addRecords` method like this:

```
format.format("%s", "    ModelRenderer " + Arrays.deepToString(ListOfBoxes) + ";\n");
```

Comment: Thanks, although i fear this might cause problems later in line, as later, i will be doing 'test1.addBox(int,int,int,int,int,int)' using the same String[], so it would be [test1, test2, test3].addBox(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int) which i don't think would work

Comment: You hadn't provided all the relevant code, so I can't tell for sure, but deepToString most certainly is not the cause of your problems. The only way it could be a problem is if you send null inside or the array  to be deepToString-ed has null's in it. All that deepToString does for a String array is that it "transforms" the array of individual strings {"first","second"} to a single String "[first,second]". Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: i believe you, but the format that deepToString is giving me is not what i need, thanks for your suggestion though